# what's meaning that sign of assignment

Tags: c++, function, variable-assignment

i don't understand assignment in the following line. i think, **setBit** is a function but it's assigned a value.

```
bool setBit(const unsigned int which) = 0;
```

Comment: -1 small code snippet out of context

Answer (score 11):

It's not assignment. It indicates a [pure virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions). A class with one or more pure virtual functions is called an "abstract class", and cannot be instantiated on its own. Derived classes *must* implement the function in order to avoid being abstract classes themselves. So the meaning of `=0` here is, "my derived classes will provide this function".

Answer (score 4):

This is a virtual function. when you declare a function and assign it 0 you are creating a function without an implementation

When you inherit this class you can them create a concrete implementation for this function

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you missed the word *virtual* before *bool*. It's the declaration of an *abstract* function in a class. In C++ abstract functions are called *pure virtual* functions and you tell the compiler that it is abstract by specifying *= 0* at the end of the declaration.